# Manage sorted data into index section and cell in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to build a tableview like iPhone's "Contacts" list?

My original data is in `JSON`, which is downloaded and packed in to a object of Model Class called `Article.swift`. "article" is its element.

```
article.name = rawData["A_Name_Ch"] as! String
article.name_EN = rawData["A_Name_En"] as! String
article.location = rawData["A_Location"] as! String
article.image_URLString = rawData["A_Pic01_URL"] as? String
........
........
```

and data is sorted by article.sorted:

```
func downLoadLatestArticles(){
    Article.downLoadItem { (articles, error) in
        if let error = error {
            return
        }
        if let articles = articles {
            self.articles = articles.sorted(by: { $0.name_EN! < $1.name_EN! })
        }
    }
}
```

We'd like to use article.name as the key to sort, showing article's info on tableview by section title(A,B,C..), rolling side index-table A~Z, and lead to next view with detail data when clicking the cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return articles.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListTableCell", for: indexPath) as! ListTableCell

    var article : Article

    let imageURL: URL?
    if let imageURLString = article.image_URLString {
        imageURL = URL (string: imageURLString)
    }
    else {  imageURL = nil   }

    if let c = cell as? ListTableCell {

        c.nameLabel?.text = article.name;
        c.name_ENLabel?.text = article.name_EN;
        c.locationLabel?.text = article.location
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your Array ready to use, you can use this method to sort your array elements.

```
articles = articles.sorted { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending }
```